# How to set the value of a pandas dataframe column with an operation over the same column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to execute the following sentence in a python script over a Pandas dataframe:

```
boxes_df["delivery_date"] = (dateutil.parser.parse(boxes_df["delivery_date"]) + datetime.timedelta(weeks=weeks_before)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not Series
```

How can I make the such a calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want

```py
df["delivery_date"] = (df["delivery_date"].apply(dateutil.parser.parse) + datetime.timedelta(weeks=weeks_before)).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

But more pandas way is

```py
df["delivery_date"] = (pd.to_datetime(df["delivery_date"]) + pd.Timedelta(weeks=weeks_before)).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

`.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` can be replace by `.dt.date`